# Ionic2 toggle component change event not firing

Tags: events, typescript, angular, ionic2

My app is rendering fine, but why would the `change` event function `updateItem(item)` not be firing?

**Template:**

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="#item of items">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{item.title}}</ion-label>
        <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="item.completed" (change)="updateItem(item)"></ion-toggle>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options>
        <button primary (click)="editItem(item)">
          <ion-icon name="edit"></ion-icon>Edit
        </button>
      <button secondary (click)="deleteItem(item)">
        <ion-icon name="delete"></ion-icon>Delete
      </button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
```

**Class:**

```
export class Todos {
...
  updateItem(item) {
    alert(1)
    this._todosService.update(item).subscribe(
      response => { this.getItems(); }
    );
  }
... 
}
```

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5034 I haven't found `<ion-toggle>` to fire a `change` event. Can you link to docs what events it fires? I don't use Ionic myself.

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toggle/Toggle/

Comment: Did you try the `ngModelChange` event?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

According to [the Ionic documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toggle/Toggle), you can do that :

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="item.completed" (ionChange)="updateItem(item)" checked="false"></ion-toggle>
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Hey thanks. Yeah this wasn't working back when I asked the question. But this is correct now.

Comment: ionChange should be mentioned in docs  
ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toggle/Toggle

Answer (score 6):

**update**

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="itemCompleted"></ion-toggle>
```

```
export class Todos {
  get itemCompleted() {
    return item.completed;
  }
  set itemCompleted(value) {
    item.completed = value;
    updateItem(item);
  }

  ...
  updateItem(item) {
    alert(1)
    this._todosService.update(item).subscribe(
      response => { this.getItems(); }
    );
  }
  ... 
}
```

**original**

When `[(ngModel)]="..."` works, this

```
(ngModelChange)="updateItem(item)"
```

should work as well and probably do what you try to accomplish.

Comment: On further testing, this is not a satisfactory answer as it calls the change event when the toggles are being rendered for the first time. This is not the desired result. It appears that the (change) event not firing is actually a bug in the latest beta of Ionic 2.

Answer (score 3):

If initial value true then ionChange is not useful because its is trigger every time.

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="item.completed" (ngModelChange)="updateItem(item)"></ion-toggle>
```

Hope this is helpful !

Comment: initial value true in my case and it's not triggering ngModelChange